# Android permission and ProtectionLevel

Tags: android, permissions

How Do we find what level of Android protection is required for a specific permission.

Lets say we have `android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER`([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER))

What protection level does it fall into?([docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html))

- Regular
- Dangerous
- System or Signed
- Signed

Answer (score 6):

You can find some permission with there levels here:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

and an other solution is the following code sample:

```
getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo(name,  0).protectionLevel
```

in you're case is this the infos:

```
<!-- Allows an application to watch and control how activities are
         started globally in the system.  Only for is in debugging
         (usually the monkey command).
         <p>Not for use by third-party applications. -->
    <permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER"
        android:label="@string/permlab_runSetActivityWatcher"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_runSetActivityWatcher"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually Creators of respective API sets the permission depending who are the recipients of this API.

Best way is to grep the source code for the respective API permission.

Android document fairly states what is intended for 3rd party and what not. Permission is usually "Normal" for all things intended for Normal.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER

To answer your permission question 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Look at fragment .. it is signature permission.

Allows an application to watch and control how activities are
         started globally in the system.  Only for is in debugging
         (usually the monkey command).
         Not for use by third-party applications

```
permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER"
    android:label="@string/permlab_runSetActivityWatcher"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_runSetActivityWatcher"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"
```